# Dog Age Converter Python always puts out 7

Tags: python

```py
DogAgePerYearInHuman = 7
HumanAge = input("What is your age?")
HumanAgeIfDog = DogAgePerYearInHuman * HumanAge

print(f"If you would be a dog you would be {DogAgePerYearInHuman} years old")
```

The output is always 7

Comment: what does `type(HumanAge)` give?

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to the constant variable - `DogAgePerYearInHuman` - in your print statement. You need to replace that with the result of your product: `HumanAgeIfDog`.

Per Epsi95's comment, you also need to cast the input as integer (`int(HumanAge)`). Otherwise you'll get another unexpected result.

Comment: Also Luffy needs to cast `HumanAge` to integer. use `HumanAgeIfDog = int(HumanAgeIfDog)`

Comment: DogAgePerYearInHuman = 7
HumanAge = input("What is your age?")
HumanAgeIfDog = int(HumanAgeIfDog) = HumanAge * DogAgePerYearInHuman

print(f"If you would be a dog you would be {HumanAgeIfDog} years old")
int(HumanAgeIfDog)  is still an Error